# Amazon RDS SQL Server Change Database Owner

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I know I can't make my user in RDS a sysadmin...but can I at least change the database owner from rdsa to my own user? If I use SSMS and go to change the Owner in the database properties, I get the message:

```
The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database
```

Why do I want to do this instead of just adding my user to the db_owner role?

I have indexed views I want to create, and when trying to do so, I get the error

```
Index cannot be created on view '...' because the underlying object '...' has a different owner.
```

I know that I can manually use ALTER AUTHORIZATION on the underlying objects to allow this, as described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/sql-server-2008-cannot-create-index-on-indexed-view. But I really don't want to do that for every single object referenced by every one of my indexed views.

I'm certainly open to suggestions on alternative approaches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Index cannot be created on view '...' because the underlying object
>   '...' has a different owner.

This is the real problem you're trying to solve, right? Changing the database owner (which would be done by running `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<dbname> TO <loginname>`) is just a red herring.

To solve this problem is unlikely you need change th owner of the underlying object, is far more likely you want to change the owner of the **view**, and probably correct solution is to create the view in the same schema as the underlying table:

```
create view schema.indexedView
with schemabinding
as
select ... 
from schema.table
where ...
```

Note that I say 'likely' and 'probably', this is not excuse I'm uncertain of the solution. Is because only *you* can tell us who the owner should be, based on the specific business rules, audit settings and access permissions of your site. Also, the fact that everything is database contained (the table, the indexed view, the schema containing the table and the owner of the schema) it means that the fact that this is an RDS instance is completely irelevant.

Comment: Indeed the view is intended to be in a separate schema. Can I change the owner of the secondary schema so all of it's objects belong to the RDS admin account? or is there another way?

Comment: You can have both schemas be owned by the same user: [`alter authorization on schema::foo to bar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx)

Comment: Bingo. I set the secondary schema owner to the RDS built in admin account. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know how to change the db owner?  I have imported a database "Import Data Tier Application" and now the owner is rdsa, so i can delete or rename it.  Just being able to delete it would be goo to tidy things up.